# Upload files in RadAsyncUpload control from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I would like to know if its possible to upload files in RadAsyncUpload control from codebehind.

Instead of pressing "Select" button of RadAsyncUpload control and selecting files and uploading it, I would like to upload a list of files present in a directory into RadAsyncUpload control from codebehind.

If we can upload files from code behind, is it possible for you to show me a demo.

Please note, i have RadAsyncUpload control as a usercontrol registered in a page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The upload process through the codebehind is not allowed.

RadAsyncUpload is based on the [HTML input type=file element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which allows to upload files only from the client's machine. The user is allowed to select a file from his/her machine and upload it through the select file dialog of the input element.